# Show url only for one reference

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex`.

Like I use zotero to retrieve metadata of references, I have plenty of urls into my .bib file. In most cases, I don't want the url to be printed (because it is only the url of the publisher webpage presenting the book). So I use the following line with `url=false` :

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
     hyperref,
     backend=biber,
     isbn=false,
     doi=false,
     url=false,
     date=year]{biblatex}
```

However, in some case, the url is important: for example if I cite an online article which has no physical publisher.

How can I tell to biblatex to print the url for some references (explicitly indicated) without removing all (useless) urls in my references to keep only the useful ones?

Comment: How do you indicate the references? You can use `DeclareSourceMap` for this issue.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel With \autocite{key}

Comment: Maybe those articles should be of type @online, for example? Even with url=false, biblatex will include urls for reference types where that information is essential and it sounds as if that is the sort of entry you may be talking about here. See the user manual for details of which types will still pick up the url when url=false is passed to the package.

Comment: The question really is: How would you like tot tell `biblatex` which URLs not to discard? There are several ways for `biblatex` to get rid of the URL but they all require you telling `biblatex` which to keep (or not to keep). The best way, obviously, is to remove superfluous URLs from the `.bib` file, there is no point in them being there, if they serve no purpose in the bibliography. But of course that is quite tiresome and tedious if your bibliography is compiled by an external programme. You could add a marker (a keyword via `keywords`) to entries whose URL is important.

Comment: The `url` macro could then be extended to only print URLs if a particular keyword is set. But of course that also requires a tedious sift through your `.bib` file and might be equally time consuming as deleting unnecessary URL fields, so we probably don't win a lot here. The most on-the-fly way would probably be to define a `\DeclareBibliographyCategory{needsurl}`, use a macro `\newcommand{\dispurlinbib}[#1]{\addtocategory{needsurl}{#1}}`, and redefine the `url` macro to only print URLs of entries that are in `needsurl`. If you are interested in this, I might write up an answer.

Comment: @cfr Using "online" entry is not a solution because it gets ride of the "journal" field. In my case, it is an article on a online (only) journal (so with no pages, no place, no publisher, only the journal name). The journal name is very important as well as the url.

Comment: @cfr, though `@online` may not work some situations (@ppr's on-line journals), you are correct that it overrides the `url=false` flag. Like @ppr, I am also using [zotero](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/18337/bibtex-document-class-for-zotero-item-types-report-and-thesis/) and I noticed that when exporting, Web Page entries are classified as `@misc` (a poor choice IMHO).  As I do not use anything specific to the `@misc` citations, I found it helpful to use [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to replace them with `@online`: `sed -i 's/@misc{/@online{/g'  zotero_export.bib`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To tell `biblatex` on the fly whose URL to print, try the following.

For this to work, you *must not* pass `url=false` to `biblatex`.

We define a new category (these can be very easily dealt with on the fly and via input in the `.tex`, not the `.bib` file): `needsurl`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{needsurl}
```

We also redefine the URL macro to print the URL only if the entry is in the category `needsurl`.

```
% this is basically the standard macro from `biblatex.def`,
% augmented with the logic for `needsurl`
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifcategory{needsurl}
    {\printfield{url}%
     \iffieldundef{urlyear}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printurldate}}
    {}}
```

Then there is a short command to indicate to `biblatex` that a certain entry needs its URL displayed.

```
\newcommand{\entryneedsurl}[1]{\addtocategory{needsurl}{#1}}
```

You can use it anywhere you like in the document, but keep in mind that `\entryneedsurl` does not print anything, it just tells `biblatex` to print the URL, if the entry appears in the bibliography.

It is used as you would expect, if you want the entry `markey` to have its URL displayed, just issue `\entryneedsurl{markey}` anywhere in the document.

The `\entryneedsurl` could also be incorporated into certain `\cite` macros, so you could have a `\citebiburl` macro that does everything `\cite` does, but adds the entry to the category `needsurl`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, hyperref, backend=biber, isbn=false, doi=false, date=year]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{needsurl}
\newcommand{\entryneedsurl}[1]{\addtocategory{needsurl}{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifcategory{needsurl}
    {\printfield{url}%
     \iffieldundef{urlyear}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printurldate}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  A\entryneedsurl{markey}B
  \cite{markey,ctan}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image: MWE output]

Comment: This seem more complicated than I would expect.  The `bib` file has the information regarding what type each citation is, e.g., `article`, `book`, `online`, or `misc`.  It seems there should be a way to automate this so that `biber` recognizes if the citation is the specified type and include the url.

Comment: @stvn66 Showing the URL per type is much easier. If you use `url=false` it will only be shown for `@online`, in [Biblatex: Suppressing urldate does not work (\clearfield)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278890/35864) you can see how this can be extended for other types.