# Biblatex: Suppressing urldate does not work (\clearfield)

Tags: biblatex

I've read through alot of entries here with a similar topic (like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187643/biblatex-how-can-i-suppress-some-fields-for-multiple-entry-types) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46787/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-urls-from-appearing-in-biblatex-citations)). The solution does not work for me and I'm kind of deperate now.

That's why I'm asking this question again: How do I suppress the **urldate** field in biblatex.

I am using Miktex with Biber 2.2.

#### My MCE (adopted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187643/biblatex-how-can-i-suppress-some-fields-for-multiple-entry-types)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
}{}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test-lit.bib}
@book{Abook,
  author = {AAAAbook, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{Bonline,
  author = {BBBBonline, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@collection{Ccollection,
    editor = {CCCCColletionEditor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Charlie},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2010-01-01},
}
@incollection{Dincollection,
    author = {DDDDincollection, D.},
    year = {2002},
    crossref = {Ccollection},
    title = {Delta},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test-lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Abc.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

#### My Document looks like this:

[image: Picture]
<sub>(source: [ahschulz.de](http://www.ahschulz.de/pub/overflow/biblatex_urldate.png))</sub>

I am also confused that the urldate is mentioned in the last entry, but there is no urldate in the bib-File.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\clearfield{urlyear}` should do it (date fields are broken apart internally, at which point only the date parts exists). The `urldate` in `Dincollection` is inherited from `Ccollection` via the `crossref` feature.

Comment: You can use `\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{book}}
               or test {\ifentrytype{collection}}
               or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}} }
    {\clearfield{url}%
     \clearfield{urlyear}}
    {}}` (modulo line breaks)

Comment: Note that Marco Daniel's answer ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46787/35864)) uses the correct `urlyear` while the other answer uses `urldate`, the fact that there are quite some (accepted) answers out here that use `urldate` makes me think that this once worked, but doesn't any more.

Comment: See also [Excessive fields in biblatex chicago author-date style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147749/35864)

Comment: The urldate mentioned in the last entry comes from `Ccollection` (via `crossref`).

Answer (score 17):

According to the comments of moewe, `urldate` is split up into `urlyear`, `urlmonth` and `urlday`. Removing `urlyear` solves the problem.

**This MCE works:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test-lit.bib}
@book{Abook,
  author = {AAAAbook, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{Bonline,
  author = {BBBBonline, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@collection{Ccollection,
    editor = {CCCCColletionEditor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Charlie},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2010-01-01},
}
@incollection{Dincollection,
    author = {DDDDincollection, D.},
    year = {2002},
    crossref = {Ccollection},
    title = {Delta},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test-lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Abc.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also write it shorter (by removing `url` and `urlyear` if entry type is not `online`): `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{online}{}{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}}`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple solution: use the `url=false` option of `biblatex` package.

Citation from `biblatex` documentation:

> `url=true,false (default: true)`
>
> This option controls whether the  `url` field and the access date is printed. The option only affects entry types whose `url` information is optional. The `url` field of `@online` entries is always printed.

### Result:

> [image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,url=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{filecontents}{test-lit.bib}
@book{Abook,
  author = {AAAAbook, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@online{Bonline,
  author = {BBBBonline, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@collection{Ccollection,
    editor = {CCCCColletionEditor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Charlie},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2010-01-01},
}
@incollection{Dincollection,
    author = {DDDDincollection, D.},
    year = {2002},
    crossref = {Ccollection},
    title = {Delta},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test-lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Abc.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will of course remove URLs for everything except `@online`. For a more fine-grained control one needs either `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}{}}` or some version of `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\togglefalse{bbx:url}}{}}`.